# Including self in the context

Tags: django

Is it advisable to include self in the context data that is being passed in the templates in django?

```
def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
   return {'self': self}
```

Does it have some security vulnerabilities or anything that may have a bad impact? Thank you.

Comment: It is not necessary: `self` is already passed to the context, through `view`.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it advisable to include self in the context data that is being passed in the templates in django?

It is **already included**, as **`view`**. Indeed, you can for example use:

```
{{ view.request.GET.some_key }}
```

> Does it have some security vulnerabilities or anything that may have a bad impact?

Templates are rendered at the server side, so as long as you don't expose sensitive data when *rendering* the template, you're fine. Of course if you pass more to the context, there is more "power" to expose sensitive data.